# Rewarding user for rate app in android

Tags: java, android, google-play

Is there a way to check if an user has rated your application in google play and only after reward him?

I'm actually using this simple code

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to rate it?")
                        .setTitle("Rate this app");
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                builder.setPositiveButton("Do it now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getContext().getPackageName());
                        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

                        goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                        try {
                            startActivity(goToMarket);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getContext().getPackageName())));
                        }
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Not now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
```

I don't want to check it in the intent, but I want to be sure that he has voted it before rewarding

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic (but also, see https://play.google.com/about/storelisting-promotional/ratings-reviews-installs/)

Comment: This reward type is rejected by app's shops. This is not allowed.

Comment: I just don't understand why it's rejected. I mean, I don't want them to rate it positively, I want to have a feedback (good or bad) so I can improve what I can.